# Yii2 Проблема .SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'n_category_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, yii2, форма

Ситуация следующая- добавляю на сайт форму с добавлением новости и категорией новости.
Таблица News:
id
news_name
news_category
news_text
n_category_id

Таблица Category
id
category_id
category_name

поле n_category_id таблицы news подтягивает данные из category_id таблицы category.
Связь таблиц прописана в моделях:

```
public function getCategory(){
        return $this->hasMany(NewsCategory::class, ['category_id'=>"n_category_id"]);
    }

и

 public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostNews::class, ['n_category_id' => 'category_id']);
    }
```

View:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['class' => 'form-vertical', 'id' => 'testForm']]);
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'news_name'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'news_category'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'news_text')->textarea(['rows' => 5]); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Опубликовать!', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']); ?>
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

При заполнении формы пишем в категорию одну из реально существующих в базе. (По моей логике название существующей категории должно матчиться с id категории и отдавать в таблицу news).
На выходе получаю ошибку из заголовка.
Понимаю, что не дописал код который будет перед отправкой формы подтягивать данные из таблицы категорий, но не понимаю как. 2 суток гугления увы результата не дали.

*Добавлено*

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        // name, email, subject and body are required
        [['news_name', 'news_category', 'news_text'], 'required']
    ];
```

у таблицы категорий правила отсутствуют.

контроллер:

```
 public function actionNews()
    {
        $model = new PostNews();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($model->save()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Успешный успех!');
                return $this->refresh();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Ошибся!');

                $this->layout = 'basic';
                return $this->render('news', compact('model'));
            }
        }
    }
```

DROPDOWNLIST

```
$catslist = \app\models\NewsCategory::find()->all();
$items = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($catslist,'category_id','category_name');
$params = [
    'prompt' => 'Укажите категорию новости'
    ];
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'news_category')->dropDownList($items, $params); ?>
```

Comment: Суть проблемы в следующем. Поле в структуре таблицы может иметь значение по умолчанию либо не иметь его. Если оно есть, и в запросе на вставку записи поле вообще не указано, то присваивается значение по умолчанию. Однако если его нет - возникает указанная ошибка (сервер не может присвоить значение, даже NULL, по собственной инициативе). Так что проблема не в коде, а в структуре таблицы, и именно там и надо проблему лечить.

Comment: то есть я правильно понимаю, по коду никаких дополнительных прописываний айди->save() не нужно? Когда проставлял поле null, то информация всё равно не подтягивалась. Может стоит вообще переделать таблицы и упростить их как-то. А чисто теоретически, откуда и в какой момент интерпретатор должен понять что вот поле n_category_id которое мы не заполняем в поле должно подтянуться из другой таблицы. Не пойму вот эту схему.

Comment: Да я в этой уйне-2 ничего не понимаю... просто рассказал, что за проблема на уровне MySQL. Где её, собственно, и надо решать. Наверное. Или, если есть возможность средствами yii задать значение по умолчанию для поля, сделай так.

Comment: А как они могут быть по умолчанию если они тянутся с другой таблицы?

Comment: покажите (добавьте в вопрос) как сохраняете данные и что написано в rules у каждой модели

Comment: Добавил информацию в вопрос.

Comment: @Stieglits не совсем понятно. вы описываете структуру таблицы News: `id news_name news_category news_text n_category_id`, а в методе используете модель `PostNews`. Пока не понятно почему. .Потому что присылаются данные одной модели, а загружать (судя по коду) вы пытаетесь их в другую..........какова задача в целом? .........и кстати,  в БД у `n_category_id` в БД что прописано? not null?

Comment: class PostNews extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function TableName()
    {
        return 'news';
    }                                                                                                                                             Задача простая на самом деле- при добавлении новости(таблица news) выбирать в одном из полей категорию из списка категорий (news_category) и в баз новостей правильно подтягивалась выбранная категория. В БД у n_category_id прописано not null.

Comment: Тогда у вас в принципе не правильно сделана БД. Потому что ссылка на другую таблицу (в вашем случае `n_category_id`) на то и существует, чтобы по ней выбирались везде категории и по связям можно было обратиться к другой сущности. А в представлении можно использовать `dropDown` или `select2` для отображения множества из таблицы категорий, где будет ключ- идентификатор категории, значение - имя категории. И тогда всё будет сохраняться отлично. Колонка `news_category` тут неуместна.....

Comment: .Но если прям уж так хочется делать как вы хотите, то это надо будет костылить: после `$model->load` надо выбрать из таблицы категорий идентификатор, где имя такое же, как пришло в `news_category` и этот `id` уже записывать в модель `PostNews`. А потом только сохранять её. Так что, по сути, нужно, чтобы из формы приходил `category_id`

Comment: Добавил дроппдаунлист, может в нем что-то делаю не так,

Comment: Алексей, а чем конкретно неправильность базы, чтоб я на будущее понимал? есть news.n_category_id которая должна тянуть инфу из category.category_id, вроде ничего сверхъестественного.

Comment: @Stieglits да, должна тянуть инфу, но вы ведь не используете именно эту возможность и эту логику. У вас для чего-то в таблице с новостями хранится наименование категории (`news_category`). Ну, или не знаю что это конкретно, на первый взгляд именно это. А судя по тому, что у вас есть ссылка на категорию в ввиде `n_category_id`, то нужно именно её использовать, а вы не используете как раз, например при выводе категорий в форме. И вся остальная инфа о категориях в таблице новостей БД (и в модели), кроме `n_category_id` не нужна.

Comment: то есть по сути стоит удалить news_category и плясать вокруг n_category_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['class' => 'form-vertical', 'id' => 'testForm']]);
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'news_name'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'news_category'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'n_category_id')->dropDownList([/* Категории */]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'news_text')->textarea(['rows' => 5]); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Опубликовать!', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']); ?>
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // name, email, subject and body are required
        [['news_name', 'news_category', 'news_text', 'n_category_id'], 'required']
    ];
```

Comment: Прыдущая ошибка ушла, когда в правилах прописал реквайрд. А дропдаунлист пробовал , всё равно не прописывает и не тянет айди. ТЕперь вот такая ошибка. То есть всё равно не хочет.                       
    [n_category_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => Необходимо заполнить «N Category Id».

Comment: n_category_id вытяните список категорий ключ значения ->dropDownList(MyCategoryModel::find()->select('category_name', 'id')->indexBy('id')->column());

Comment: Если я правильно понял.Заменил поле news_category  на <?= $form->field($model, 'n_category_id')->dropDownList(\app\models\NewsCategory::find()->select('category_name', 'id')->indexBy('id')->column()); ?>                                                                                                     Выходит теперь ошибка [0] => Необходимо заполнить «Категория новости»., суть таже

Comment: Попробовал также добавить поле news_category и получил новую ошибку                    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: !!!! Есть небольшое продвижение, возможно прояснит ошибку. поля формы n_category_ id и  news_category должны соответствовать друг другу исходя из таблицы категорий, то есть если имя категории Сатира, то n_category_id должно соответствовать 3, тогда добавляется в базу запись, иначе ошибка SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452